# Adding multiple Jar files to Inelij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I'am working on a project which requires adding multiple  jar files to intelij  idea as a plugin but  only one jar  files gets added as a plugin to the IDE.

Comment: I hope this link will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: its not helping as i have 2 jar files of 2 different projects  and i have added the jar files in the following location " C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.4\plugins\brampton\lib " . and the problem is that only the first jar file is getting added to my project